# Using importXML in google sheet

Tags: html

I'm trying to pull the `S&P 500` sector weightings from Morningstar `(http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/index-summary?t=SPX&region=usa&culture=en-US)`

into google sheets.

I've tried

```
=IMPORTXML("http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/index-summary?t=SPX&region=usa&culture=en-US","//th")
```

but this gives me more data than I need and not the percentages for each sector.

What would be the proper code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? This retrieves values. `http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/index-summary?t=SPX&region=usa&culture=en-US` is in a cell of "A1".

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@id='sectorWeightings']//td[@align='right']")
```

If you want the data as a table, how about this?

```
=QUERY(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@id='sectorWeightings']//tr")),"Select * where Col2<>''"), "Select Col2, Col3")
```

[image]

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. One quick follow up question. What would the proper code be in order to also to pull the "as of dd/mm/yyyy" at the bottom of the table?

Comment: @Evan Comer The value you want is this? ``=QUERY(IMPORTXML(a1, "//td[@class='text1 gry paddintTop']"),"Select Col1")`` If I misunderstand your comment, I'm sorry.